# Access Denied for custom user roles

Tags: permission-denied, access-denied

I have created a new user role "Call center". When submit a order from admin section with user role "Call center" access, it showing "Access Denied" error.

I have follow your other reply but didn't understand, please provide step by step solution.

Comment: What tool/OS you are referring to?

Comment: [os - ubuntu] on magento site

Comment: To create a new user role you need to have admin priviledges or run it as sudo command. Did you have to put your user password again to ensure that you are running it as sudo user?

Also what is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: What is the "other reply" you are referring to? There do not seem to be any answers below.